# width of floating divs

Tags: html, css

I have two floating divs.
I would like the first div to be 100px wide and the other div's width to be the rest. Something like:

```
<div style="float:right;width:100px;height:100px;background:black;"></div>
<div style="float:left;width:100%;height:100px;background:yellow;"></div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82Kb8/).

**There is one rule: I don't know the width of the page!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take the `float:left;width:100%;` off the second div, it should work the way you want it.  When a block is floated to the right, the non-floated objects flow around it.  Since you've set the `height` to be the same for the two blocks, they will line up nicely.

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82Kb8/10/) to show how this works.

Comment: This works in the example I add. But in my real problem the height is different and there are round corners on the right div so the other div is on its background.

Comment: @Naor: This is why you should make sure your test case matches the real situation.

Comment: as for the round corners that show the background: add margin to the yellow div: http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/82Kb8/13/

Comment: @ptriek: You helped me. Write your own answer in order to accept your answer.

Comment: @Naor:  My answer provides a solution to your specific question.  Please expand your original question to provide more information about your situation if this answer doesn't do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Floating divs get occupy their width based on their contents. otherwise you need to specify the width based on the container of both the divs.

```
<div style="float:right;width:100px;height:100px;background:black;"></div>
<div style="float:left;height:100px;background:yellow;">It will occupy space
    based on contents</div>
```

OR do it by parent container...

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <div style="float:right;width:100px;height:100px;background:black;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;width:300px;height:100px;background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how they made it the old times )

```
<style>
#content { width:auto; height:auto; padding:10px 10px 10px 105px; position:relative; float:left; }
#content #column { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding:10px 5px 10px 10px; width:100px; }
</style>

<div id="content">
    <div id="column">Right part</div>
    Left part
</div>
```

Sorry, haven't been making layouts for a while, maybe it's easier when you don't have to support EI6 ) But it should be absolutely **resolution-proof, unlike using only float blocks**.